# XCode 4.2 auto add synthesize and method bodies

Tags: xcode

Is there anyway to make xcode (4.2) automatically add synthesize and the empty method bodies to the implementation file (for properties and methods defined in the interface) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in solution for that in 4.2. You could try creating a shell script that searches your header for properties and then adds the @synthesize lines at the right place.

Why don't you use the latest (4.4) version instead? 4.4 can automatically synthesize the ivars for you. All you have to do is declare a @property and Xcode takes care of the rest.

Comment: I am still using snow leopard but its good to know that future versions take care of this. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I've just installed XCode 4.5 and it's stopped auto @synthesize-ing properties defined in the interface! Anyone else had this? How do I get this back?

Comment: Did you override both the getter and setter of that property? In that case you have to manually synthesize.